# Recommended way of checking if a certain string has a specified character more than once

Tags: c#, string, char

Firstly I understand that there are several ways to do this and I do have some code which runs, but what I just wanted to find out was if anyone else has a recommended way to do this. Say I have a string which I already know that would have contain a specific character (a ‘,’ in this case). Now I just want to validate that this comma is used only once and not more. I know iterating through each character is an option but why go through all that work because I just want to make sure that this special character is not used more than once, I’m not exactly interested in the count per se. The best I could think was to use the split and here is some sample code that works. Just curious to find out if there is a better way to do this.
In summary,
I have a certain string in which I know has a special character (‘,’ in this case)
I want to validate that this special character has only been used once in this string

```
const char characterToBeEvaluated = ',';
string myStringToBeTested = "HelloWorldLetus,code";

var countOfIdentifiedCharacter = myStringToBeTested.Split(characterToBeEvaluated).Length - 1;

if (countOfIdentifiedCharacter == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Used exactly once as expected");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Used either less than or more than once");
}
```

Comment: if you want to investigate further try the benchmark.net tools, they will show e.g. the runtime and memory advantage of indexof vs. split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string`'s [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0) methods:

```cs
const char characterToBeEvaluated = ',';
string myStringToBeTested = "HelloWorldLetus,code";

string substringToFind = characterToBeEvaluated.ToString();
int firstIdx = myStringToBeTested.IndexOf(substringToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal);
bool foundOnce = firstIdx >= 0;
bool foundTwice = foundOnce && myStringToBeTested.IndexOf(substringToFind, firstIdx + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0;
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/VZVB48669)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If I may ask, why is IndexOf considered better?

Comment: @Dre If you have more than 2 commas, you still only have to evaluate to the second comma. You don't need to evaluate the entire rest of the string. If you have a string with 200 commas in it, you don't need to create 201 new strings to determine that yes, there is more than one comma.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `LINQ` `Count()` method:

```
const char characterToBeEvaluated = ',';
string myStringToBeTested = "HelloWorldLetus,code";
var countOfIdentifiedCharacter = myStringToBeTested.Count(x => x == characterToBeEvaluated);

if (countOfIdentifiedCharacter == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Used exactly once as expected");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Used either less than or more than once");
}
```

This is the most readable and simplest approach and is great if you need to know the exact count but for your specific case @ProgrammingLlama's answer is better in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it will be helpful for someone certainly who is also interested to find the count

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer using a custom method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    const char characterToBeEvaluated = ',';
    string myStringToBeTested = "HelloWorldLetus,code";

    var characterAppearsOnlyOnce = DoesCharacterAppearOnlyOnce(characterToBeEvaluated, myStringToBeTested);

    if (characterAppearsOnlyOnce)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Used exactly once as expected");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Used either less than or more than once");
    }
}

public static bool DoesCharacterAppearOnlyOnce(char characterToBeEvaluated, string stringToBeTested)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringToBeTested.Length && count < 2; ++i)
    {
        if (stringToBeTested[i] == characterToBeEvaluated)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count == 1;
}
```

The custom method `DoesCharacterAppearOnlyOnce()` performs better than the method using `IndexOf()` for smaller strings - probably due to the overhead calling `IndexOf`. As the strings get larger the `IndexOf` method is better.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that IndexOf creates a substring, or that it evaluates characters again?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, sorry I think misread you implementation (quickly skimming over it) -  the var name substring to find deceived me. I timed both approaches and this was faster but what I'm saying about the substring is probably wrong. Will update my answer.

Comment: I was curious about the performance thing so I benchmarked yours and my own with BenchmarkDotNet ([code](https://pastebin.com/B4B9GuST)). Yours does indeed perform better than mine until the max string size is set to 300 (average generated size: 154 characters) and then mine seems to be consistently faster after that. I guess perhaps the internal call to the native method made by IndexOf has some overhead until the string gets long enough.